# CITemperatureAndTint filter value range

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-image, cifilter

There seems to be no documentation on the range of values allowed for CITemperatureAndTint filter, nor does it show up on querying the filter at run time. I tried the range 1000 to 6500 for color temperature, it works but what is the allowed range?

Comment: Unfortunately, that appears to be a private filter. (I queried iOS 12.0.1 to verify.) I think you are on your own. (And good luck with getting approved in the app store.)

Comment: Are you serious, it's a public one!!! - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CITemperatureAndTint

Comment: I stand corrected. Looks like `inputNeutral` and `inputTargetNeutral` both have the same range: 0-13000.